# Vue project in pre-production server when build stop in Building for production

Tags: node.js, vuejs3

- No errors.
- Not stop.
- Same node versions, and yarn in all computers
- Same system Ubuntu 22.04

Latest tries

```
❯ VUE_CLI_DEBUG=true PARALLEL=false  yarn build --report
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vue-cli-service build --report
All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.


⠧  Building for production...

...
```

I do not know what else to do.

When something doesn't give me a debug, I feel unprotected as a system administrator and developer.

### Also

- rm node_modules
- rm yarn.lock & package-lock.json
- rm all caches in user home, relative a yarn, npm, ...
- Update machine to 16 cores (VPS in big machine with 32 cores)
- More ram..
- htop not show problems about this. But without `PARALLEL=false` there are a lot of processes in parallel mode with too many threads of node

Any idea or help for debugging this issue?